# R Bookdown image disappears

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am having an issue with bookdown, not sure the reason why.

When add images (these are files, so I use knitr::include_graphics) like this:

````
# This is a minimal example

I want the image "mas.gif". Where is it?
```{r mas, echo=F, fig.cap="image", ref.label="fig:mas"}
knitr::include_graphics("mas.gif")
```

Hmmm...no clue!
````

The chunk just disappears in the epub, md, tex and pdf files.

What could be wrong? It used to work some while ago...

Comment: Please make your example reproducible.

Comment: I changed it so that my example is reproducible, thank you for your suggestion!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `, ref.label="fig:mas"`, like this

````
# This is a minimal example

I want the image "mas.gif". Where is it?
```{r mas, echo=F, fig.cap="image"}
knitr::include_graphics("mas.gif")
```

Hmmm...no clue!
````

See the [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html#fn6) by **bookdown** package's author:

> If we assign a figure caption to a code chunk via the chunk option `fig.cap`, R plots will be put into figure environments, which will be automatically labeled and numbered, and can also be cross-referenced. The label of a figure environment is generated from the label of the code chunk, e.g., if the chunk label is `foo`, the figure label will be `fig:foo` (the prefix `fig:` is added before `foo`). To reference a figure, use the syntax `\@ref(label)`, where `label` is the figure label, e.g., fig:foo.

Comment: oh you are right I'll try that as soon as I can, and give my feedback!